# Launch camera application (Windows 10) using AutoIt

Tags: windows-10, autoit

I am trying to launch my camera application (Windows 10) using [`ShellExecuteWait()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ShellExecuteWait.htm) (as I want my script to wait until I close the camera app). But I can't seem to get it to work. I tried following code from the help file:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Camera()

Func Camera()
   ;Execute Camera and wait for Camera to close
   Local $iReturn = ShellExecuteWait("notepad.exe")

   ;Display the return value
   MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "The return code from Notepad was: " & $iReturn)

EndFunc
```

This displays Notepad. When you close it, a message box appears with the return value. However, as I change `notepad.exe` to `explorer.exe`, `ShellExecuteWait()` seems to fail (and the message box appears straight away).

You can't open the camera on Windows 10 using `Run("camera.exe")`; like with `explorer.exe` this fails and the message box appears straight away.

This is the code that I want to work:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Camera()

Func Camera()
   ;Execute Camera and wait for Camera to close
   Local $iReturn = ShellExecuteWait("explorer.exe", "shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App")

   ;Display the return value
   MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "The return code from Notepad was: " & $iReturn)

EndFunc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShellExecuteWait()` may not work as expected with server-ish processes like explorer. `explorer.exe` is always running. Another call to it will only tell the already running `explorer.exe` to display an additional window (like many browsers will not create another instance of itself but just a new tab). You can examine the current process hierarchy with tools like *ProcessExplorer* (from the *Sysinternals Suite*). There you can see, that notepad is actually a sub-process of your autoit script where `explorer.exe` stays a child of `svhost.exe`.

You could still try something like this:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Camera()

Func Camera()
   ;Execute Camera and wait for Camera to close
   local $iPID = ShellExecuteWait("explorer.exe", "shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App")
   Sleep(3000)
   WinWaitClose("Camera")

   ;Display the return value
   MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "The Camera was closed." )

EndFunc
```

With that, your script waits until no more windows called "Camera" exist. Please mind that the result will depend on the OS language (e.g. for me it's "Kamera"). You may be able to use the tool *AutoIt Window Info* to find language independent characteristics.